# Rails get array of IDs if model has a collection with an ID in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

High level what I'm trying to do.
I have a `House` model and a `House` has_many `Rooms`.  Both House and Room have an id property.  I'm trying to get an array of House ids that contain a rooms with a certain id:
data: (rails 4.2.6)

```
houses = [{
  id: 1,
  rooms: [{ id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
},{
  id: 2,
  rooms: [{id: 2}]
}]
```

pseudocode

```
House.where(rooms: contain(id: 2))
```

this should return [1,2] because both houses have room id of 2

```
House.where(rooms: contain(id: 1))
```

this should return [1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
House.joins(:rooms).where(:rooms => {:id => 5}).pluck(:id)
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you care about is the `id` values you can use [`pluck`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck):

```
House.where(...).pluck(:id)
```

Comment: inside the where lambda, how do you reference the current House instance's rooms collection?

Comment: There is no "current house" when you're calling class methods. That's a query constructor, not an instance method.